# Components keeps Rerendering in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rerender

I have a component and it is performing very badly. When I debugged the problem I found out that these two child components keeps re rendering for no reason.

Can someone help me see whats the problem here. In my logs I'm getting `Rendering Categories` and
`Rendering Queries` over and over

Here is my implementation:

```
const categories = useMemo(() => ({
chefs: {
  name: 'Chefs',
  title: getMessageByKey('explore.chefs'),
  image: ChefsCategory,
  available: true,
},
recipes: {
  name: 'Recipes',
  title: getMessageByKey('explore.recipes'),
  image: RecipesCategory,
  available: true,
},
products: {
  name: 'Products',
  title: getMessageByKey('explore.products'),
  image: ProductsCategory,
  available: false,
},
buisness: {
  name: 'Buisness',
  title: getMessageByKey('explore.buisness'),
  image: BuisnessCategory,
  available: false,
},
}))



const queries = useMemo(() => ({
    trending: {
      name: 'Trending',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.trending'),
      image: <FireFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <FireWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getTrending_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getTrending_Recipes,
    },
    new: {
      name: 'New',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.new'),
      image: <LightningFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <LightningWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getNew_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getNew_Recipes,
    },
    top: {
      name: 'Popular',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.popular'),
      image: <HeartFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <HeartWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getPopular_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getPopular_Recipes,
    },
    verified: {
      name: 'Verified',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.verified'),
      image: <VerifiedFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <VerifiedWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getVerified_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getVerified_Recipes,
    },
  }))
...

<View style={styles.categoriesContainer}>
        {console.log('Rendering Categories')}
        {
          Object.values(categories).map((category) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.categoryContainer} 
                key={category.name} 
              >
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                  onPress={category.available ? ()=> handleCategoryClick(category.name) : () => showToast({type: 'error', text1: 'Coming Soon', text2: 'This feature is Coming Soon'})}
                >
                  <Image
                    style={[styles.categoryImage, selectedCategory === category.name ? styles.selectedCategory : '']}
                    source={ category.image }
                  />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <Text style={[styles.categoryName, {color: theme.textColor}]}>{category.title}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          }
        )}
      </View>

      <View style={styles.queriesContainer}>
      {console.log('Rendering Queries')}
        {
          Object.values(queries).map(query => {
            return (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                key={query.name}
                onPress={()=> handleQueryClick(query)}
              >
                <View style={[styles.queryContainer, selectedQuery === query.name ? styles.querySelected : '']}>
                  <Text style={selectedQuery === query.name ? styles.queryTextSelected : styles.queryText}>{query.title}</Text>
                  {
                    selectedQuery === query.name ? 
                      query.selectedImage : 
                      query.image
                  }
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
          }
        )}
      </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the dependency arrays in both the useMemos. By default, useMemo will run on every state change if there is no dependency array.

If you want these to be evaluated only once - on mount, please add an empty dependency array as the 2nd argument.

If you want them to be evaluated every time the variables change, add all the variables to the dependency array.

Comment: still the same, the component keeps rerendering

Comment: Is it rerendering whenever the state changes or infinitely? 
If it is rerendering infinitely, check 2 things, 
1. move console.log("Rendering queries") and console.log("Rendering Categories") inside the useMemo, before returning the object. 

If the console.logs print infinitely, 
2. add a useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounting")
}, [] to check whether there's something in the parent causing it to mount again and again

Comment: I added the two logs in the useMemo and the useEffect and both are only logging once. So, the problem isn't there

Comment: Great! Then we know it's some part of the state that is changing besides categories or queries. You'll need to share the rest of the component body for us to identifiy.